# Sliding window Minimum Size Subarray Sum

Tags: python, sliding-window

Given an array of positive integers nums and a positive integer target, return the minimal length of a
subarray
whose sum is greater than or equal to target. If there is no such subarray, return 0 instead.

Example 1:

Input:

target = 7, nums = [2,3,1,2,4,3]

Output: 2

Explanation:

The subarray [4,3] has the minimal length under the problem constraint.

I was able to successfully complete the question with the sliding window technique but I am looking for some help to optimize the time run /execute & generate the output. Current time complexity is O(n).

```
class Solution(object):
    def minSubArrayLen(self, target, nums):
        """
        :type target: int
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        current_sum=nums[0]
        possible_combinations=[]
        result=float("inf")
        start=0
        end=0
        target_sum=target

        if sum(nums)<target:
            return 0
        elif target in nums:
            return 1
        else:
            while start < len(nums) and end < len(nums):
                if current_sum >= target_sum:
                    result=min(len(nums[start:end + 1]), result)
                    current_sum -= nums[start]
                    start += 1
                elif current_sum < target_sum:
                    end += 1
                    if end < len(nums):
                        current_sum += nums[end]
            if result ==float("inf"):
                return 0
        return result
```

Comment: Are you looking for a solution with time complexity faster than O(n)?

Comment: Any modifications to code which can make it more efficient, I submitted the same in leetcode i m in last 5% of the total time run

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `len` anywhere inside of your `while` loop.

Comment: I removed 1 len inside the while loop did not help

Comment: There were 4 of them.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 significant performance problems:

- You can remove the part:

  ```
    if sum(nums)<target:
        return 0
    elif target in nums:
        return 1
  ```

  This runs through your array twice on every run, even if it will probably only apply to a small percentage of test cases. Your `while`-loop covers those cases, taking a little more time though (so maybe test the effect, as if e.g. 95% of the test cases have `sum(nums)<target`, removing this edge case will slow your code down).
- In

  ```
   result=min(len(nums[start:end + 1]), result)
  ```

  you create a copy of the subarray just to get its length, while you know the length already: it is `end-start+1`. So you can replace it with

  ```
   result = min(end-start+1, result)
  ```

Additionally, you may want to try to end the loop early if the result is `1`, as it cannot get lower than this - but it depends on the test data if that has a performance effect, or if this additional condition even increases the average run time:

```
while start < len(nums) and end < len(nums) and result != 1:
```

You can get rid of some of your comparisons, but those will probably only have a marginal performance impact (and probably don't make the code prettier or more readable). Some examples that come to mind:

- you do not need to test for `elif current_sum < target_sum`, since it is the only option left after `if current_sum >= target_sum` is false, so you can just use `else`
- you could add the test if you reached the end of your array into the else-block (as only there, `end` is increased), then you can remove it from the while loop (so you save one comparison when `start` is increased), e.g. something like:

  ```
   while start < len(nums) and result != 1:
       if current_sum >= target_sum:
           ...
       else:
           end += 1
           if end >= len(nums):
               break
           current_sum += nums[end]
  ```
- similarly for the `start < len(nums) and result != 1`-test that is only relevant if you are in the if-block

As a side note, your function currently would fail on an empty list (because `current_sum=nums[0]` would fail). It might be specified as not empty somewhere (although not by your docstring), apparently does not cause problems (until it does) and fixing it will most likely not improve performance, but it would fail any code audit, so you might want to keep it in mind.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the kind & elaborate explaination.

Answer (score 0):

You see this : `len(nums[start:end + 1])` this is nothing but `end - start + 1`

In other words you are slicing the `nums` repeatedly which is not necessary.

You could write it as :

```
result = min(end - start + 1, result)
```